# Encoding record samples for expectation maximization algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, record, matching, expectation-maximization

First, I'm a programmer without a data science background, so my working knowledge of statistics is quite limited.

I'm creating an entity matching tool to match records across internal datasets. I want to use the probabilistic matching technique described in these documents*. I have a good understanding of how the technique works and how to apply it, except for the derivation of agreement/disagreement weights using expectation maximization (EM).

Specifically, I'm unclear on how to encode my record pairs into the `double[][]` format required for

The EM implementation I have available is the Apache Common Math [MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/fitting/MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization.html).

Here is a concrete example: matching company records.

A company has two fields: `name (string)` and `country (enum)`, and I want to generate the m and u probabilistic weights using EM. How do I create the `double[][]` dataset for each field to feed into EM?

In the case of `name`, it is a string so there will be an approximate agreement / disagreement, using some string similarity method (edit distance, phonetic index, etc., the details aren't relevant here)

In the case of `country`, my data is normalized so agreement will only occur on an exact match. However certain countries are over and under represented. So a record with an under-represented country should have a higher weight than one with an over-represented country.

1. What exactly do the values in the inner `double[]` mean/represent?
2. How many entries/columns should there be?
3. How do I encode the records into the `double[]`?

---

* the documents describing the probabilistic matching technique using EM

- [An Overview of Record Linkage Methods](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK253312/)
- [Death registrations to Census linkage project - Methodology and Quality Assessment - M AND U PROBABILITIES](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/Lookup/3302.0.55.004Chapter292011-2012)
- [Estimating Match Weights and Thresholds Algorithms for Master Person Index](https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/projects/iopenmpdm/Estimating%20Match%20Weights%20and%20Thresholds%20White%20Paper.pdf)